# How to add onClick event on card view

Tags: android, view, click

I Am very beginner in Android development and it's my first post on *stackoverflow* .  And I to want ask that how I can add an click Event on card view so that whenever I click on each card the respective layout open

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView               xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,UnusedAttribute" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Arbaz"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Arbaz"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add your java file too. the above one is not the complete code to answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to trigger anything when user clicks the card, you need to put a OnClickListener on the card.

```
CardView card_view = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view); // creating a CardView and assigning a value.

card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do whatever you want to do on click (to launch any fragment or activity you need to put intent here.)
        }
    });
```